# The maximum of real function with 4 prime parameters and $\lfloor \ \rfloor$

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ be prime numbers such that $a>b>c>d$. Let $x$ be an integer greater than $a$.

Let $f(x) = \left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right) – \left(\left(\dfrac{x}{ab}\right)  + \left(\dfrac{x}{ac}\right) + \left(\dfrac{x}{ad}\right)\right) + \left(\left(\dfrac{x}{abc}\right)  + \left(\dfrac{x}{abd}\right) + \left(\dfrac{x}{acd}\right)\right) - \left(\dfrac{x}{abcd}\right) $

Let $g(x) = 
\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{a} \right\rfloor –
\left(\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{ab} \right\rfloor +
\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{ac} \right\rfloor +
\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{ad} \right\rfloor \right) + 
\left(\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{abc} \right\rfloor +
\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{abd} \right\rfloor +
\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{acd} \right\rfloor \right) -
\left\lfloor \dfrac{x}{abcd} \right\rfloor -1$

What value of $x$ results in the maximum difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ (i.e. $f(x) - g(x)$) and what is the value of the difference in terms of $a,b,c$ and $d$?

Edit: I changed the square brackets to parentheses since they were causing confusion.

There are multiple values of $x$ where the difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ reaches a maximum. If you graph the difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, you will notice that the curve is cyclical with a period equal to $a\times b\times c\times d$. In other words $f(z) - g(z) = f(z + abcd) - g(z + abcd)$ for any integer $z$.

For example, $a=7$, $b=5$, $c=3$, $d=2$.
By plotting the difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, I have found that
the maximal difference occurs at $x=76 + 210n$ where $n$ is any integer.
The value of the maximal difference is $\frac{398}{210}$.

Why does the maximum occur at $x=76$? Why is the maximal difference equal to $\frac{398}{210}$?

[image: Max difference occurs at x=76+210n and has a value of 398/210]

Edit2: Notice that the difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ reaches a peak at $x=an-1$ where $n$ is an integer. This is because the difference between the first terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is at a maximum.
$\left(\dfrac{an-1}{a}\right) - \left\lfloor \dfrac{an-1}{a} \right\rfloor = \dfrac{a-1}{a}$.

In my example where $a=7$, the peaks occur at $x = 48,76,90,118,132,160,202,$etc. All these values are in the form $x=7n-1$ and the largest peak occurs at $x=76$.

Comment: Where on earth does this come from?

Comment: I get a maximum difference of 7, but can't put it in terms of the quite arbitrary variables without coefficients of 0 everywhere. okay that may be minimal.

Comment: Could you answer to the question of @Klangen ?

Comment: No ambiguity for $\lfloor r \rfloor$ (the greatest integer $\leq r$), **but** have the square brackets $[r]$ a meaning (closest integer ?) or are they to be considered as parentheses ?

Comment: I doubt the answer is unique

Comment: The function $g(x) + 1$ is roughly the size of the set "integers less than $x$ which are multiples of $a$ but not of $b, c$ or $d$", so $f(x) - g(x) - 1$ is the difference between the "heuristic prediction and the actual value". The answer should be unique modulo $abcd$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Most of the work was already done by OP. This answer is a kind of summary.

In order to find the maximum difference $\max_{x\in\mathbb{N}}\{f(x)-g(x)\}$ the constant term $-1$ of $g(x)$ is not relevant and will be neglected.  We  denote with  $\{x\}$  the  *[fractional  part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)* of a real number $x\geq  0$.
\begin{align*}
x=\lfloor x \rfloor+\{x\}\qquad\qquad   0\leq  \{x\}<1
\end{align*}

Taking primes $a>b>c>d$ we can write the difference as function $h:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ with
\begin{align*}
h(x)&=\frac{x}{a}-\frac{x}{ab}-\frac{x}{ac}-\frac{x}{ad}+\frac{x}{abc}+\frac{x}{abd}+\frac{x}{acd}-\frac{x}{abcd}\\
&\qquad-\left\lfloor\frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{ab}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{ac}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{ad}\right\rfloor\\
&\qquad-\left\lfloor\frac{x}{abc}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{x}{abd}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{x}{acd}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{abcd}\right\rfloor\\
&=\left\{\frac{x}{a}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{ab}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{ac}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{ad}\right\}\\
&\qquad+\left\{\frac{x}{abc}\right\}+\left\{\frac{x}{abd}\right\}+\left\{\frac{x}{acd}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{abcd}\right\}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> In order to better see what's going on we look at OP's example $a=7,b=5,c=3,d=2$ and  consider according to (1):
>   \begin{align*}
> &\left\{\frac{x}{7}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{35}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{21}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{14}\right\}\\
> &\qquad+\left\{\frac{x}{105}\right\}+\left\{\frac{x}{70}\right\}+\left\{\frac{x}{42}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{210}\right\}\to  \max\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We  deduce  from (2):
>
> - The dominant part is $\left\{\frac{x}{7}\right\}$ which is maximal whenever $x=7n-1$, $n\geq 1$ and zero whenever $x$ is a multiple of $7$.
> - Since each of the denominators is a divisor of $210$, we consider WLOG $1\leq x=7n-1 \leq 210$, $n=1,\ldots,30$.
> - The first term $\left\{\frac{x}{7}\right\}$ evaluated at $x=7n-1$ is the constant $\frac{6}{7}$.

We conclude from the three aspects above:

The maximum of $h$ is given as

\begin{align*}
&\max_{1\leq x\leq 210}h(x)\\
&\qquad=\max_{1\leq x\leq 210}\left(\left\{\frac{x}{7}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{35}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{21}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{14}\right\}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.+\left\{\frac{x}{105}\right\}+\left\{\frac{x}{70}\right\}+\left\{\frac{x}{42}\right\}-\left\{\frac{x}{210}\right\}\right)\\
&\qquad=\max_{1\leq  n\leq 30}\left(\frac{6}{7}
-\left(\frac{(7n-1)\mathrm{mod}(35)}{35}\right\}-\left\{\frac{(7n-1)\mathrm{mod}(21)}{21}\right\}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\left\{\frac{(7n-1)\mathrm{mod}(14)}{14}\right\}+\left\{\frac{(7n-1)\mathrm{mod}(105)}{105}\right\}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left\{\frac{(7n-1)\mathrm{mod}(70)}{70}\right\}
+\left\{\frac{(7n-1)\mathrm{mod}(42)}{42}\right\}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.-\left\{\frac{(7n-1)\mathrm{mod}(210)}{210}\right\}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}

Calculation gives a maximum value for $n=11$ resulting in

\begin{align*}
h(x)=h(7n-1)=\color{blue}{h(76)=\frac{94}{105}\doteq 0,8952}
\end{align*}

> In general we obtain as in (3)  for  primes $a>b>c>d$ the maximum of $h$ as:
>
> \begin{align*}
> &\max_{1\leq x\leq abcd}h(x)\\
> &\qquad=\max_{1\leq  n\leq bcd}\left(1-\frac{1}{a}
> -\left\{\frac{(an-1)\mathrm{mod}(ab)}{ab}\right\}-\left\{\frac{(an-1)\mathrm{mod}(ac)}{ac}\right\}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad-\left\{\frac{(an-1)\mathrm{mod}(ad)}{ad}\right\}+\left\{\frac{(an-1)\mathrm{mod}(abc)}{abc}\right\}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left\{\frac{(an-1)\mathrm{mod}(abd)}{abd}\right\}+\left\{\frac{(an-1)\mathrm{mod}(acd)}{acd}\right\}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.-\left\{\frac{(an-1)\mathrm{mod}(abcd)}{abcd}\right\}\right)
> \end{align*}